# How to extract array data from Ajax to Python flask?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am having problem extracting data sent from the Ajax call to the python flask backend. 
I am able to extract the key:value string pair only from the request.args object. But the problem is the data I am sending is of mixed type :
e.g.  `data:{'data':'stringdata','Email':['abc@example.com','def@example.com'],'checkbox':'[true,true]'}`

when I am reading this data from the request.args in my python module.. I am able to get request.args['data'] which returns 'stringdata' but for the other keys like request.args['Email'] I am getting BAD REQUEST errors.

I have tried `JSON.stringify` the data separately for each item plus the whole data object but none of it is working.
I have also tried setting the data type and the contentType in the Ajax call but still no good.

```
$.ajax
        ({
              url: '/abc',
              data : {
                  "data": 'stringdata',
 "Email": ['abc@example.com','def@example.com'] ,
 "Hbeat":[true,true],
 "Creport" : [true,true] ,
 "Treport" : [true,true] ,
 "Preport" : [true,true]
                },
              success: function(data) 
              {

              },
              complete: function() 
              {
              }
          });
```

Here the python part where I am trying to get the data.:

```
@app.route('/abc', methods=['POST','GET'])
def checkingdata():
    print(request.args)
    print(request.args['data'])
    print(request.args['Email']) # this is where I am getting errors.
```

I expect to get the data as the form they are in. e.g. where I am passing the list of emails I need to get them as list. and where there are single string values I should get them as single string values.

thanks so much for your time. Please help if you can.

Comment: try `request.json` not `request.args`

Comment: The [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) requires double quotes and will not accept single quotes, nor will the parser

Comment: @waynetech also tried that.. didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `request.args.getlist`:

```
emails = request.args.getlist('Email')
```

Comment: Thanks but I guess there needs to be some more manipulation.... `ImmutableMultiDict([('{"data":"stringdata","Email":["abc@example.com","def@example.com"],"Hbeat":"[true,true]","Creport":"[true,true]","Treport":[true,true],"Preport":[true,true]}', '')])` 
this is the response.args I am getting.... applying `request.args.getlist('Email')` give bad request error

Comment: error is because you need to return some kind of response. Your code above in question doesn't.